# Как установить Yii2 в не пустую папку с помощью Composer?

Tags: ubuntu, yii2, composer

Хочу установить `yii2` с помощью `Composer`.

1. Создал папку
2. Сделал в папке `Composer init`
3. Потом `Composer install`
4. Потом `composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0"`
5. Теперь хочу скачать Yii в папку, чтобы была иерархия myProject/файлы yii
6. С помощью cd выхожу в общую папку,  с помощью ls вижу папку myProject
7. Делаю composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic myProject

Но тут получаю ошибку  `Project directory myProject/ is not empty`.

Как правильно решить задачу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем в папке делать `composer init` и `composer install` ?

Если хотите установить yii2 в папку myProject, то

1. Устанавливаете composer

   - `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`
   - `mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`
2. Потом ставите плагин глобально `composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0"`
3. `composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic` (вместо basic путь к Вашей папке)
4. запускаете `php requirements.php`
5. Меняете подключение к базе данных

Более наглядно  [тут](https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/start-installation/)

Если у Вас,  установлен `composer` и плагин `fxp/composer-asset-plugin`, то первые два пункта пропустите.